# Trying to understand what's going on in this PHP code?

Tags: php

I program in other languages but my job involves reading PHP and I'm trying to understand part of this view page (we use MVC).

```
<?
foreach ($slides as $i => $slide) {
  ?>
  <li class="yui3-carousel-element<?=$i > 0 ? ' hidden-node' : ''?>">
  <?
```

1. Why is the loop surrounded by `<?` and `?>` ? I thought those go on either end of the entire PHP script, but instead I'm seeing them scattered throughout the whole thing.
2. That ternary expression seems to just be floating....it's not being `echo`'ed or `print`'ed or concatenated to anything....not to mention it weirdly seems to be comparing the number `0` to something I can't make out....it's not a string...it's an `li` element with no closing tag?? In php?? I'm very confused.

Comment: 1. `<? ?>` just indicates to the server that there is some executable code.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 1):

The `<?` and `?>` tags are short tags saying that PHP code is inside of them. When they are closed, it goes back to simply outputting HTML.

The `<?=`that you see on the line is simply a shorthand for `<?php echo`

Personally I would have probably left the tag open at the start, then do echo on the line in the loop. What is there is the equivalent to the following:

```
<?php
foreach ($slides as $i => $slide) {
    $hiddenElement = $i > 0 ? ' hidden-node' : '';
    echo '<li class="yui3-carousel-element'.$hiddenElement.'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?` `?>` are called short tags in PHP. They indicate the start and end of PHP code. The ternary is also wrapped with the short tags. That ternary is actually appending something to the class depending on whether or not the current index of `$slide` is greater than 0. The `li` is HTML and it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

1. The loop is surrounded by those because it's exiting PHP code and entering HTML code. For example, you can do: `<?php /*code here blah blah*/ if (...) { ?> <div>ha</div> <?php } /*more code*/ ?>`. In PHP, if you don't wrap stuff with `<?php ?>`, then it's executed as HTML code.
2. That statement with `<?=` is a shortcut to echo'ing. It literally says `<?php echo (($i > 0) ? ' hidden-node' : '' ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `<?` is used as an opening tag for php-code and `?>` as a closing tag. PHP can be mixed with other languages like HTML as seen in your example.
2. Actually it is being `echo`'ed, that's what the `=`right after the `<?` does. It is nothing else than a short command for `echo`. The other thing with the `?` and `:` is another short form. Written out the whole thing equals `if($i > 0) echo ' hidden-node'; else echo '';`.

So the code adds `<li>`-Elements for every slide and for every slide except the first one it adds the class 'hidden-node', which most likely hides all other elements except the first one when the code gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

the `<?` and `?>` is shorthand for the [php tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

after that is clear you can see that the 
`<li class="yui3-carousel-element<?=$i > 0 ? ' hidden-node' : ''?>">`
part is checking if `$i` is greater than 0 and displaying the `hidden-node` when it is